# Logging output in JavaScript promise shows [object object]?

Tags: javascript

Logging response from JavaScript promise API call is showing [object object] in the console window? how to wait for the result and log?.

below is the following code for which I am getting [object][object].

```
const estimateGas = (to, data, network) =>
  new Promise((resolve,reject) =>
  axios.post(getUriByNetwork(network), {
  jsonrpc : "2.0",
  method : "eth_estimateGas",
  params : [{
  "to": to
  }],
  id : 1
})
.then(function (response) {
resolve(response)
console.log(` estimateGas ${response}`)
})
.catch(reject)
)
```

Comment: Use `console.log('estimateGas', response)`. You are trying to convert an object to a string...

Comment: `String(Object)` does it, instead try `JSON.stringify(Object)`

Comment: also can we talk about you using antipatterns with promises inside a promises constructor? There is literally no reason to wrap entire thing into promise

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski to add a link here: [What is the explicit promise construction antipattern and how do I avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743)